# Image resolution is changing in some phones

Tags: android, firebase, android-camera, android-camerax

I'm trying to analyze the image so I set 160, 120 inside setTargetResolution() function but when I run the app it is changing the resolution to 320, 240 in my phone but working fine in other phones. My phone is Redmi 6 pro.

```
   HandlerThread analyzerThread = new HandlerThread("FaceDetection");
        analyzerThread.start();

        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis =
                new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                        .setTargetResolution(new Size(160, 120))
                        .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                        .build();

        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, image -> {
            int rotationDegrees = image.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees();
            if (image == null || image.getImage() == null) {
                return;
            }
```

Comment: are you using newest version of CameraX? there were some [bugs and fixes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/5c1aed8c4c502a74eb4ee6d30fe2089f4afcaf11) some time ago

Comment: I'm using beta04

Comment: have you tried with currently newest `beta06`? I see some changes in `beta05`, description says only javadoc, but maybe something else changed?

Comment: Does Redmi 6 pro support 160x120? The resolution selection is on a best effort basis. It can't be done if the device doesn't support it. In this case you may want to re-sample it yourself.

Comment: It was working when I was using alpha version of cameras and now I updated it to beta06 but still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be able to fixed after correcting the target resolution setting from

```
.setTargetResolution(new Size(160, 120))
```

to

```
.setTargetResolution(new Size(120, 160))
```

To set the target resolution, developers can refer to the following java doc description in https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis.Builder#setTargetResolution(android.util.Size):

> The resolution Size should be expressed in the coordinate frame
> after rotating the supported sizes by the target rotation. For
> example, a device with portrait natural orientation in natural target
> rotation requesting a portrait image may specify 480x640, and the same
> device, rotated 90 degrees and targeting landscape orientation may
> specify 640x480.

The reason of why the setting Size(160, 120) can't obtain the result size as 160x120 in newer CameraX versions of library:

> In older versions, CameraX only compared area size of the target
> resolution to find the closest size. Therefore, 160x120 was still
> selected. In newer versions, CameraX try to find a closest supported
> size that can box the target resolution calibrated by the target
> rotation. The code doesn't set target rotation. I guess the device is
> in portrait orientation, so the default target rotation is ROTATION_0.
> After calibrating the target resolution by ROTATION_0, CameraX will
> try to select a closest supported size that can box the size of
> 120x160. Finally, 320x240 is selected.